# SMB/CIFS pipelining

Tags: smb, cifs, pipelining

Is pipelining a feature of the SMB/CIFS protocol? I found that SMB2 does have a pipelining mecanism but no clear answer is available for the previous version. I have a network capture with several SMB Transaction Secondary messages on top of several NetBIOS session service messages, is that common on a network?

Comment: What is your definition of pipeline in this context? That would probably depend on the network and what you do on it.

Comment: pipelining, that is, sending additional requests before the response to a previous request arrives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SMBv1/CIFS has special "AndX" commands, which can chain to another command in the same packet – although only a few specific commands can be part of the chain. (There are 8 "AndX" commands in total – OPEN_ANDX, READ_ANDX, WRITE_ANDX, and a few others).

> Batched messages using the AndX construct were introduced in the LAN Manager 1.0 dialect. Batched messages reduce the number of messages required to complete a series of commands by sending multiple command requests or responses in a single message. SMB commands that apply the AndX construct are known as "AndX Commands", and are identified by the NT LAN Manager convention of appending "_ANDX" to the command name. Messages of this type are known as AndX Messages.
>
> …
>
> AndX Messages contain a construct, conceptually similar to a linked-list, that is used to connect the batched block pairs. The resulting list is referred to as an AndX Chain.
>
> …
>
> Each AndX Command has a specific list of commands that can follow it in an AndX Chain. Each command's list of permitted follow-on commands is documented in the command's corresponding subsection of section 2.2.4, SMB Commands.

Quoted from the official Microsoft protocol documentation:

- MS-CIFS [2.2.3.4 Batched Messages ("AndX" Messages)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee442210.aspx)
- MS-CIFS [3.2.4.1.4 Sending Any Batched ("AndX") Request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441840.aspx)
- MS-CIFS [3.3.5.2.4 Receiving any Batched ("AndX") Request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441934.aspx)
- CodeFX [CIFS Explained](http://www.codefx.com/CIFS_Explained.htm)

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I think my capture is not following MS documentation because several TRANSACTION_SECONDARY requests on top of each other does not seem to be allowed. Any idea how this happened? Could this be crafted by a malware or can a normal SMB implementation do that?